# jQuery masonry not working with Safari

Tags: jquery, wordpress, safari

I'm using [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) with a WordPress installation and it works fine in every browser but Safari (both Win and OSX). Could this be related to some jQuery/WebKit issues with `.load()` firing too early? I'm quite new to jQuery/JavaScript, so any help is greatly appreciated.

This page doesn't work in Safari: http://tangomitstil.de/news/

While this page (for some reason) does: http://tangomitstil.de/info/unterricht/

The problem is not related to the number of items (I'm experiencing the same problem with my dev version with a rather large set of test posts), @font-face embedding, use of images, or the [Infinite Scroll plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/).

Here is the code called in the header section:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) { 
    // We can only load masonry on window.load because of embedded swfobjects
    jQuery('.content').masonry({
        singleMode: true,
        resizable: true,
        animate: false
    }); // initiate masonry
    jQuery('.content').infinitescroll({
        navSelector: "div.navigation",
        // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
        nextSelector: "div.navigation div.nav-previous a",
        // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector: ".content div.post",
        // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        loadingText: "L&auml;dt weitere Beitr&auml;ge..."
    }, function(newElements) {
        jQuery(this).masonry({
            appendedContent: jQuery(newElements)
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the "DOM ready" event, which fires after the "load" event (when images have finished loading etc.).

jQuery has a nice shortcut for that. Instead of

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  // ...
});
```

do

```
jQuery(function() {
  // ...
});
```

Or, simply:

```
$(function() {
  // ...
});
```

When you do not use any other JS framework in parallel, it's safe and convenient to use `$` in place of `jQuery`.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply but that doesn't work either. My content does get "masonified" with (window).load. However, the "left" property is always set to 0 in safari, so no second column is rendered.

Comment: @Illyria: Just to rule out any timing problems: Use `$(function() { setTimeout(function() { /* yourstuff */}, 1000); });` to delay the call for a second. If that's not helping, then *timing* is not the problem.